# Height Fix for a admin dashboard template in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am using a admin dashboard template in Bootstrap in which I need help. 
[image]
As you can see from the image above, I have a fixed sidebar, and the main page content wrapper. The main page content has an id of `page-wrapper. The issue was this one:

```
#page-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

This one has an automatic adjust of the page-wrapper's height, which works for a table with several records (assuming there is no pgination yet). However, it will not work for a table with few records. That black section there will fill up the empty space.
I've tried setting a height:

```
#page-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 700px;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

[image]

But as I continue to develop on this web app, I just don't feel a fixed height since I will be adding more test data in it in the fture. Can somebody please help me? Thanks.

I tried

```
#wrapper, #page-wrapper{
      position: absolute;
}
```

But the page-wrapper shrinks and leaves a black space next to courses. (Update)

Comment: care to share the code/fiddle?

Comment: do you have the porblem with your table.

Comment: @Graham I have the problem with that black section, I want to remove that one from the page wrapper and just have a white background when the records are few.

Comment: use your inspect elements on your browser (right click and select inspect elements.) and select this `black` section. then select it's css and try to change it.it will show your changes realtime and anything won't happen to your code. and one other thing.is your table scroll when count is hight.

Answer (score 0):

**As per my understanding, You are trying To fix left side bar**

I have few suggestion for Desktop and small device as well to handle resposiveness.

**Desktop**: **Calculate the height of viewpoert of your window and set same same height to next column.** So to do so first fetch your windows height and store it to in variable and then assign it your left sidebar and done :)
Both will always same height

**Tab or Mob/ basically small devices:** As a UX perspective user should able to approach navigation tab all the time so either you can go with hamburger menu or else put it as a icon top or bottom of the screen like any app.

for a reference yo can click on this link for integration of height 
http://api.jquery.com/height/

Thankyou :)

Answer (score 0):

As my understand, you wanna set page-wrapper fill all the page without fixed height. 
So, you need to set parent of page-wrapper to full height of it's container.

Asssume, `body` is parent of `#page-wrapper`. Try this:

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
}

#page-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 100%;
}
```